# svn:ignore not working for hibernate configuration files

Tags: svn

I am trying to get SVN to ignore the hibernate.cfg.xml so that whenever I merge it to other branches, it should not update hibernate.cfg.xml on that branch .

It's unable to set `svn:ignore` on the file

```
svn propedit svn:ignore http://svn.generalsentiment.com/gsui/branches/dev- 
raisin/src/hibernate.cfg.xml
svn: Cannot set 'svn:ignore' on a file   
('http://svn.generalsentiment.com/gsui/branches/dev-raisin/src/hibernate.cfg.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you set it on the directory:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore http://svn.generalsentiment.com/gsui/branches/dev-raisin/src
```

and add `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the list.

However I'd be wary of assuming that would stop it merging across branches: you might be right, it might ignore the file changes in the merged version, but I think files marked ignore but are checked in anyway get treated as normal. (I avoid that myself!) Once you've done the merge I'd `svn revert` the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your working copy just to be sure.